# Bittorrent protocol not used by uTorrent client

Tags: wireshark, bittorrent

I created a virtual environment for torrent download which included 4 virtual machines. Of the four, three machines acts as peers and the other acts as a tracker. Using `uTorrent` I created a torrent file from one of the peers and announced it to the tracker. From another peer I tried downloading the file using the torrent file created and it worked. However when I captured the network packets during the download using `wireshark`, I was surprised to see that the Bittorrent protocol was not at all used for the piece transfer. Neither it had any `request` or `have` messages. `UDP` is used for the transfer.

Why is it so? How can I instruct the client to use Bittorrent protocol for transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the use of uTP in your client.

Comment: Thank You. And also I am adding the peer manually from my client(Right click->Add peer). Should I configure something to make my tracker find the peer?

Answer (score 1):

It *does* use the bittorrent protocol. It just uses a different underlying transport protocol, µTP instead of TCP.

In essence, they are different network layers.